# If for any $\varepsilon$ exists $\delta$, does that mean that for every $\delta$ exists $\varepsilon$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, definition

For any $\varepsilon \gt 0$ exists $\delta \gt 0$,
does that mean that for any $\delta \gt 0$ exists $\varepsilon \gt 0$?

If $\delta$ depends on $\varepsilon$ such as $\delta = \frac 1 \varepsilon$, than we could wirite $\varepsilon = \frac 1 \delta$, or not?

Comment: This question makes no sense. Exists $\delta$ such that what, in relation to $\epsilon$?

Comment: of course, it is not tru

Comment: A general $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$. Obviously that if "for any $\varepsilon$ exists $\delta$" than the $\delta$ is related to the $\varepsilon$

Comment: Yes for that particular $\epsilon$

Comment: If you have no other conditions that have to be true, then of course there always exists $\varepsilon$. In fact, for any $\delta$, I choose $\varepsilon = 1$. Since $1$ exists, the problem is solved. (This works regardless of how you resolve "for each $\varepsilon$ does there exist $\delta$"; nothing about "there exist" says the answer must be uniquely determined.) Now if the question is, "For each $\delta$ does there exist $\varepsilon$ _such that the property $P(\delta,\varepsilon)$ is true,_" that could be an entirely different matter. Did you have a particular property $P$ in mind?

Comment: Some thoughts for making this a good question:  the use of $\epsilon, \delta$ suggests you are thinking about a converse to the definition of limit or continuity.  Nowhere is that mentioned, nor the function $f(x)$ which should be continuous.  It seems you want to ask something like given $f(x)$ continuous at $x=x_0$ and defined on and interval of $\delta$ around $x_0$, is there some $\epsilon$ such that $|x-x_0| \lt \delta \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)| \lt \epsilon$?  Do you see the difference in precision of the questions?  Then you should think about whether the $\lt$ should be $\le$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Consider the relation "$\delta$ is the mother of $\varepsilon$". Then for every $\varepsilon$ there is a $\delta$, but not the reverse.

Comment: If a person is called a "mother," doesn't that imply that they have at least one child? I'm not sure you can call someone "mother" if they have no children

Comment: The question is too unclear for such a straightforward answer. If $\forall \epsilon \exists \delta P(\delta, \epsilon)$, then actually yes, $\forall \delta \exists \epsilon P(\epsilon, \delta)$...

Comment: What's your point @ʙᴀᴅᴀᴛᴍᴀᴛʜ

Comment: @DonLarynx I thought for the relation "$\delta$ is the mother of $\epsilon$," it is true that for every $\delta$, there is an $\epsilon$

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Did you intentionaly swap arguments of $P$? Because $\forall \epsilon \exists \delta P(\delta, \epsilon)$ does not imply $\forall \delta \exists \epsilon P(\delta, \epsilon)$.

Comment: @tom Yes, I intentionally swapped the arguments, that's the whole point... $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ are just names, you could call the variables $x_{18}$ and Robert, it doesn't matter what their names are! I'm pointing out that the question is underspecified.